# HTTPS Proxy works when set up within Firefox using FoxyProxy, but not when set up in System Settings

Tags: network, proxy

I have confirmed that they are both set up as HTTPS proxies, use the same host and port, as well as username and password. Here is the error that safari gives when trying to go to `https://google.com`: [image: Safari can't open the page "https://www.google.com/?client=safari" because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.]

I followed the process laid out [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106742/mac-username-password-for-proxy-settings-keep-resetting-by-itself), and though it stopped the constant notifications from popping up asking for access to my keychain, it did not allow network access.